# Initialize rails form elements in controller for default value like @object.name='John'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Please tell me a way to assign form elements values in controller itself like:

def new

@form = Model.new
  @form.name = 'John'

end

Comment: What do you mean by form elements value? Do you mean the object which is passed to form like `form_for(@object)`?

Comment: yup!I don't want to use hidden fields in view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the controller's `new` action, create an instance of your model.

```
   def new    
      @model_object = ModelName.new(name: "John")    
   end
```

and in the `new.html.erb` use the instance that you created in the controller

```
<%= form_for @model_object %>
```

This way in the form you will be able to access the value of `name` attribute.

**NOTE:**
Do you really want `ModelName.new(name: "John")` or you meant to use `ModelName.new`?
Because If you use `ModelName.new(name: "John")` then every time you create an object of your Model in database(i.e., after submitting form on `new` page, `create` action would be called) it will have name as `John` unless you override it in your view.

Comment: Actually, doing this way it put default value in table for that field. The correct way to do it is in create method, @model_object.name = "John", Bdw, Thanks!!

Comment: @Amol.D Thats exactly the reason why I wrote the note. :) I wrote the code in `new` action as that was what you were expecting in the question. Glad you figured it out though.